# how to detect the number of face in an image picture

Tags: java, android

I am creating an Android face detection app and when I run it on my device it always says:
**"Sorry TakePic has suddenly stopped"**

Here is my code for face detection and I believe that this is the source of the error:

bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, selectedImage);
    TextView detect = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.detect);

```
Bitmap maskBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap( bitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565 );
Canvas c = new Canvas();
c.setBitmap(maskBitmap);
Paint p = new Paint();
p.setFilterBitmap(true); // possibly not nessecary as there is no scaling
c.drawBitmap(bitmap,0,0,p);
bitmap.recycle();

detectedFaces=new FaceDetector.Face[NUMBER_OF_FACES];
faceDetector=new FaceDetector(maskBitmap.getWidth(),maskBitmap.getHeight(),NUMBER_OF_FACES);
NUMBER_OF_FACE_DETECTED=faceDetector.findFaces(maskBitmap, detectedFaces);

k.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
detect.setText(NUMBER_OF_FACE_DETECTED);
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, selectedImage.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

What would the mistake be with this code?

Answer (score 0):

The best practice in such cases is to inspect LogCat view and look for exception messages to locate where your code is breaking.